# Why does the currency symbol show on a separate line?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a tough time working out why the currency symbol on my WooStore is showing on a different lime to the product price, any ideas?

[image]

URL: spencerdavieson.com/shop

Comment: Because of `width:100%`

Comment: `float: left;` is what you need.

Comment: It's preferred if you post the source code here instead of just a screenshot of it (the latter is often hard to read, and doesn't Google very well).

Answer (score 0):

if you remove...

```
.book-info span {
   float: left; 
}
```

from http://spencerdavieson.com/wp-content/themes/bebostore/asset/css/bebostore_woo.css?ver=1.0.0

I've tested this by checking / unchecking it on http://spencerdavieson.com/shop/

Answer (score 0):

Its in your CSS

```
.book-info span {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```